# How can I use a table with an Order List in HTML?

Tags: html, html-table

I am trying to create this table but the table's ordered list is not counting properly. how should I place the `ol` and `li` to make the list correct as `1. Coffee` `2. Tea` .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <h1>The ol element</h1>
    <table border="1">
        <ol>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ol>
                        <li>Coffee</li>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ol>
                        <li>Tea</li>
                </td>
        </ol>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <li>Milk</li>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tr>
        </ol>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid

Comment: The direct children of a table should be composed only by table rows and captions. Put any other tag inside the table cells.

Comment: have a look at my answer HTML alone wont do the trick ..... need to utilise CSS to scope everything in. HTML tends to break parent and child flow.

Answer (score 2):

Please use this to get an ordered list

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<h1>The ol element</h1>
<table border="1">
    
<td valign="top" style="padding-right:20px;">
    <ol>
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Tea</li>
        <li>Milk</li>
    </ol>
</td>
</table>
</body>
```

And if this is not helpful, please show the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <h1>The ol element</h1>
    <table border="1">
        
            <tr>
                <td>
                <ol start="1">
                    <li>Coffee</li>
                    </ol>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><ol start="2">
                <li>Tea</li>
                </ol>
                </td>
        
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <ol start="3">
             <li>Milk</li>
             </ol>
            </td>
        </tr>
        
       
    </table>
</body>
```

It seems nesting and sub nesting into rows and columns is breaking the flow to parent OL tag.

I have given an attempt with following may could work for you.
I would have sought CSS to get the desired result.

CSS EXAMPLE BELOW

```css
li {
 list-style-position:inside;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <h1>The ol element</h1>
        
                <ol type="1">
                    <li>Coffee</li>
                    <li>Tea</li>
             <li>Milk</li>
             </ol>
</body>
```

CSS Mimicking your exact styling

```css
li {
 list-style-position:inside;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;

}

li:last-child{
 list-style: square inside;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <h1>The ol element</h1>
        
                <ol type="1">
                    <li>Coffee</li>
                    <li>Tea</li>
             <li>Milk</li>
             </ol>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Coffee and Tea are in different ordered lists. Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <h1>The ol element</h1>
    <table border="1">
        <ol>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ol>
                        <li>Coffee</li>
                        <li>Tea</li>
                        </ol>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                        <li>Milk</li>
                </td>
        </tr>
        </ol>
    </table>
</body>
```